# Как для всей колонки сделать маску ввода?

Tags: c++, qt, таблицы

Имеется QTableView. Хотелось бы, чтобы для всей колонки была маска ввода. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
class YouEditMaskDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
     using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
     QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
     {
         auto * edit = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent,option,index);
         auto * lineEdit = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(edit);
         if(lineEdit)
         {
              lineEdit->setInputMask("you mask");
              /// модифицирует QLineEdit как хотим ... 
         }   
         return edit;
     }
};

table->setItemDelegateForColumn( 3, new YouEditMaskDelegate(this) );
```

Comment: Странно, но не работает

Comment: @MuhamedAli Как именно не работает? Вот мой пример: https://godbolt.org/z/6eMWjj9rr в нем, во всяком случае маска не дает вводить буквы ...

Comment: Сделал туже маску, что и у вас. в конструкторе прописал `ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(2, new EditMaskDelegate(this));` Ничего не произошло. Я могу вводить любые символы

Comment: Я извиняюсь. Там с другим была проблема связана. Спасибо большое)

Comment: И можно еще один вопрос. После установки маски lineEdit потерял свою ширину. Необходимо, чтобы он был по ширине ячейки. Как это реализовать? Заранее спасибо